# Wrong format while i getInputStream() on Android Studio from HC-06 BL Device

Tags: java, android

I use this AsyncTask to get lot of string from the HC-06.
I correct receive them but sometimes the string appear on different lines on a ListView.

For example if i send on arduino Ide jghv i got j on first line and ghv on the second
D/BLE_Activity: j
D/BLE_Activity: ghv

Can someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong?

```
private class Stream extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>  
{

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... devices)
    {
        try {
            while (btSocket.isConnected()) {

                char[] buffer = new char[256];
                int bytes;
                InputStream tmpIn = btSocket.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader red = new InputStreamReader(tmpIn);
                bytes = red.read(buffer);
                String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);

                Log.d(TAG, readMessage);

                Array.add(readMessage);

                if (isCancelled()) break;

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is how I create the ListView

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Array);



adapter.setDropDownViewResource(
                             android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

sItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Stream);
sItems.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And this is the declaration of Array and adapter

```
 List<String> Array = new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
```

Thank to all of you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to read text from inputstream line by line

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(red);
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            Array.add(line);
        }
```

Comment: The catch here is if the arduino never sends a newline this becomes an infinite loop.  Better to accumulate characters and act upon a newline accordingly.

Comment: thank you for the answer, i try your solution but it didn't work.

It miss always the first character. For example i send asd it will receive only sd  

@RamblinRose i provide the carriage return now thank you